# Is it ok to roll your own localization layer in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, n-tier-architecture

Is it ok to roll your own localization framework? I would be ok using the default .NET localization behavior (i.e., putting text in resource files named a certain way in the assembly), except that we have localized images and text that need to be rendered in DirectX in addition to WinForms and WPF.

I could put form-specific strings in one place and other strings somewhere else, but I think that it makes more sense to keep everything in one place, not to mention it will help to avoid duplicates (for domain values like Yes/No, etc.). It's also possible we may be moving this tool to another platform in the future, so it would be nice to have all the localization information in one platform-agnostic area.

I realize this is a little subjective, but I'm looking for a best practice here...I've worked on projects that take both approaches. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't ask us, ask your localization service provider what rates they charge when you hand them something non-standard.

Comment: Right now I'm just working from requirements. Localization is to come in another phase of the project...of course. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed systems in which localisation is implemented via database-stored data and metadata. If your app is already making intense use of a fast database backend, you could create a database-backed localisation layer and use it to store localised information, including textual and non-textual data. It has worked great for us in a few ocasions.

**Edit**. The details won't fit in here, but basically we mirrored the logic of the key/value resource manager that the Windows API or .NET use. We extended that by allowing resources to be grouped into groups, which can be nested arbitrarily. Resource names can be given as, for example, "ClientManagement.MainForm.StatusBar.ReadyMsg", meaning the ready message text to display on the status bar of the main form in the client management user interface. On app startup, a locale setting is read from a config file and a resource manager initialised with it; all the subsequent calls to the resource manager will be using such a locale setting until explicitly changed. We also built an administrative user interface that allowed us to edit the resources stored in the database, and even add new languages. A final comment: data to be localised is not only labels and icons on screen. Option values in combo boxes, for example, also need to be localised.

Comment: So then you guys created some kind of resource manager to obtain strings from the database based on the current culture I'm assuming? This sounds like what I'd be doing.

Comment: Thanks so much. This validates exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a localization using DB backend. We were able to create a great resource editor which allows "translator" end users to dynamically update translations (cannot do that with a resx!).   We were also able to support an approval process and group translations by module such that an entire module could be approved for use in a language, or not.

We also decided to implement the localization provider for Asp.Net, which basically does 'automatic' localization with no code by the developer. This was actually the only difficult part of the project as the interface is not well documented. It was hard to debug because it actually runs within Visual Studio host process. We used a web service to decouple the implementation which greatly simplified things.  Another good thing is that the translations are automatically cached so the DB is not working as hard.  A bad thing is that when your translation service/back end is down and if you do not precompile your asp.net web site, when the user launches a 'new' page, the compiler might decided NOT to translate the page. This behaviour remains (even after the translation service starts up again) until you force a recompile of the site.